# Pass pointers into boost::async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost

I wanted to pass a pointer into a function called by boost::async. The code where the pointer is created and the function is passed into async is not necessary to hold the memory. So I was wondering what is the best practice to manage memory in this case.

Is boost::shared_ptr or unique_ptr is safe to hold the pointer at the case?

Thank you,

Comment: Would need to see an example to comment. The documentation tells you which objects must survive the duration of thea sync call. This is normally done by holding copies of shared pointers to them in the lambda or closure that you pass as a handler

Comment: @RichardHodges Is shared pointer thread-safe? I assume unique pointer must be thread-safe.

Comment: Making copies of the pointer itself is thread safe, accessing the contents depends on the contents

Comment: I really would advise reading asio documentation thoroughly and compiling up (and running the examples therein) before you embark on your own project. asio is utterly fantastic but it has its own correct way of being used which may feel surprising to you in the beginning.

Comment: @RichardHodges is boost::async a part of boost::asio? It seems that boost::async is more like C++11's async features, while asio contains a lot of more features.

Comment: sorry, I meant boost::asio. I was on a tablet - damn you autocorrect!